# Do I need to remount directory on Ubuntu machine if I move the dir?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have an Ubuntu machine with some additional attached storage. I mount the storage and create a directory in it as follows:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdf /home/ubuntu/tempDir
cd /home/ubuntu/
sudo chmod a+w tempDir
sudo chmod a+x tempDir
```

I want to move and rename the directory, e.g.

```
mv /home/ubuntu/tempDir /some/other/location/newName
```

That is, the directory will now be called `newName`. Do I have to re-mount in order to make sure the new dir is still attached to the extra storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to remount for it to work.
Also, you may have problems if you change the directory name while the file system is still mounted.

I would suggest your unmount, rename, and then remount.

Additionally, if the mounts are in fstab you should use:
Edit /etc/fstab
unmount and mount again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

By the way, this question belongs under [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)...